# Monte Carlo simulations and sum of normal distributions

Tags: normal-distribution, simulation, monte-carlo

I am trying to predict the revenues of a portfolio of items. I want to simulate the revenues in a particular market situation in which they might increase. Each item's revenues is made up of 3 components:

Revenues per item = constant * percentage_increase_for_A(item) * A(item) + constant * percentage_increase_for_B(item) * B(item) + constant * percentage_increase_for_C(item) * C(item))

As you can see, each of the percentage increases depends on the item since each item has a different one depending on item type and region. A, B and C are just the current base values of each item that contribute to revenues.

What I plan to do is simulating each item independently by assigning normal distributions to each of the percentage increases (I will extract random values from these normal distributions in the iterations) and then what I expect to have is as many normal distributions for Revenues per item as the number of items. Then, I can sum the mean and the std of these normal distributions and get a normal distribution for the total revenues. Would this be a correct approach? Can I just sum the Revenues per item normal distributions to get a normal distribution in the end? I am not sure if it is true that if I extract randomly from normal distributions each of the percentage increases then each of the Revenues per item will also be a normal distribution.

Answer (score 0):

[The sum of normal R.Vs is also normal.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_normally_distributed_random_variables)

If you have two **independent** R.V.s $X\sim N(\mu_X, \sigma^2_X)$ and $Y\sim N(\mu_Y, \sigma^2_Y)$, and you are interested in their sum $Z=X+Y$, it can be shown that $Z\sim N(\mu_X+\mu_Y, \sigma^2_X+\sigma^2_Y)$.

There are also formulae if the R.V.s are normal but correlated.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. In my case, since the variables will be each of the item's revenues, and since they vary in a similar way (when the percentage increases - which will be extracted from normal distributions, as I said - will go up, the revenues will also go up), I expect them not to be independent. Am I mistaken? What I mean is that when the revenues of one item will go up because of those percentage increases, the others will go up too because of the same reason (but different percentage increases, of course).

Comment: In this case, the formula for the variance will be:
$Var(X+Y) = Var(X) + Var(Y) + 2Cov(X,Y)$ 
Do you think this reasoning is correct? Can I use this formula even if some revenues will not be "aligned" with the others, meaning that they go down when most of the item revenues go up? I think so, since the Covariance will just be 0 and it will be taken out from the formula. My main concern is if I can really say that the variables are not independent because of the reasoning I made in the above comment.

Comment: I don't know anything about finance, unfortunately, so I don't really understand the context. However, correlation can work both ways - it can be positively correlated (i.e. if $X$ is high, $Y$ is likely to be high) or negatively correlated (if $X$ is high, $Y$ is likely to be low). If you think you can define the behaviour of the percentage increases in a way that makes sense, the correlated sum has less assumptions to be violated.

Comment: I see, thanks for your help